# PSEXEC - Switch result

Tags: psexec

Very simple question but the documentation of PSEXEC does not explain this switch in detail:

```
-e Does not load the specified account's profile.
```

What is the use of it? What will it do exactly?

Comment: I don't think this is about programming within the scope defined in the help centre; it seems more relevant to SuperUser.

Comment: in fact, this is effectively a duplicate of [User Profiles being created on machines without logging in](https://serverfault.com/questions/50401/user-profiles-being-created-on-machines-without-logging-in) which explains what this switch does and why it might be useful.

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details concerning this question were found here : https://serverfault.com/questions/50401/user-profiles-being-created-on-machines-without-logging-in